# PostGIS: Geometry column registering as GeometryCollection, not converting to MULTIPOLYGON

Tags: postgis, geometry-conversion

I'm trying to aggregate data from a tabular data source and then join it to a geometry file (sl_adm2) in PostGIS using a primary key. The geometry file was imported using shp2psql.

```
CREATE TABLE example_geom AS 
SELECT sl_adm2_sums_alias.* , adm2_code as district_pcode 
FROM gis_schema.sl_adm2
JOIN (
    SELECT st_collect(sl_adm2.geom) AS geometry, sum(sl_sos.HEALTH) AS health_sum,
        sum(sl_sos.PROTECTION) AS protection_sum, sum(sl_sos.WASH) AS wash_sum,
        sum(sl_sos.cccm) AS cccm_sum, sum(sl_sos.food) AS food_sum, 
        sum(sl_sos.livelihood) AS livelihood_sum, 
        sum(sl_sos.education) AS education_sum, 
        sum(sl_sos.agriculture) AS agriculture_sum, 
        sum(sl_sos.HUMANITARIAN_ACCESS) AS humaccess_sum, 
        sum(sl_sos.logistics) AS logistics_sum, 
        sum(sl_sos.SHELTER_AND_NFI) AS shelter_and_wifi_sum, sl_sos.district
    FROM sl_sos 
    JOIN gis_schema.sl_adm2 ON sl_sos.DISTRICT_PCODE = sl_adm2.adm2_code
    GROUP BY sl_sos.district)
sl_adm2_sums_alias ON
sl_adm2.adm2_name = sl_adm2_sums_alias.district;
```

and then

```
ALTER TABLE example_geom
ADD PRIMARY KEY (district_pcode);
```

The aggregation and join work fine but the geometry column in the resulting table does not appear to work. Further investigation reveals that the geometry column is registering as a GeometryCollection. I tried to change this with the following code.

```
ALTER TABLE example_geom ALTER COLUMN geometry
SET DATA TYPE geometry(MultiPolygon) USING ST_Multi(geometry);
```

This gave me the below error

```
ERROR: Geometry type (GeometryCollection) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
SQL state: 22023
```

I've tried to fix this or get around it with no success. Could anyone help?

I'm using Postgres 9.4.1 with PostGIS version 2.1.5 on a Mac OS X 10.10.2.

Comment: Try wrapping your st_collect in a st_multi, eg `... st_multi(st_collect(sl_adm2.geom)) ...`.  When you say it does not appear to work, do you mean you can't view it?  Geometry collections are valid, but some software won't deal with them.

Comment: Are you happy to get rid of everything that is not a multipolygon. There might be some points or lines also.

Comment: @JohnBarça This is a purely polygonal dataset so I have no interest in points or lines.

Comment: @MickyT Using  `st_multi(st_collect(sl_adm2.geom))`, the original SQL processes fine but the final command returns the same error as above.
I cannot view the geometry in QGIS or Mapbox Studio, no. It may be that there are other issues but I can't troubleshoot until I have the file in polygon form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you may have a few invalid geometries in your base table.  You will need to do a bit of investigation.

Another thing to do would be select the well known text (ST_AsText) from your created table then look for anomalies, eg POINTs and LINEs in the collections.
You might want to add a few examples to your question.

Firstly I would make sure that your base geometries are valid

```
UPDATE gis_schema.sl_adm2
SET geom = ST_MakeValid(geom)
WHERE ST_IsValid(geom) IS FALSE
```

Then when you build your table add a check in to make sure only polygons are brought back.
You may want to consider using ST_Union rather than ST_Collect, but the depends on the result you are trying to achieve.  I recall that MULTIPOLYGONs can't having touching or overlapping parts, but I can't find a reference to it at the moment.  Even though it is slower ST_UNION will likely give you better results.  Be aware that it will dissolve boundaries between touching polygons.

```
CREATE TABLE example_geom AS 
SELECT sl_adm2_sums_alias.* , adm2_code as district_pcode 
FROM gis_schema.sl_adm2
JOIN (
    SELECT ST_Multi(st_collect(sl_adm2.geom)) AS geometry, sum(sl_sos.HEALTH) AS health_sum,
        sum(sl_sos.PROTECTION) AS protection_sum, sum(sl_sos.WASH) AS wash_sum,
        sum(sl_sos.cccm) AS cccm_sum, sum(sl_sos.food) AS food_sum, 
        sum(sl_sos.livelihood) AS livelihood_sum, 
        sum(sl_sos.education) AS education_sum, 
        sum(sl_sos.agriculture) AS agriculture_sum, 
        sum(sl_sos.HUMANITARIAN_ACCESS) AS humaccess_sum, 
        sum(sl_sos.logistics) AS logistics_sum, 
        sum(sl_sos.SHELTER_AND_NFI) AS shelter_and_wifi_sum, sl_sos.district
    FROM sl_sos 
    JOIN gis_schema.sl_adm2 ON sl_sos.DISTRICT_PCODE = sl_adm2.adm2_code
    WHERE ST_GeometryType(geom) in ('ST_Polygon','ST_MultiPolygon')
    GROUP BY sl_sos.district)
sl_adm2_sums_alias ON
sl_adm2.adm2_name = sl_adm2_sums_alias.district;
```

Comment: This works for me, but ONLY if I use ST_Union. Obviously I'm very happy to have this working but still curious what could cause that. Odder still the source polygon (sl_adm2) loads just fine and shows up as MultiPolygon in various GIS GUIs. So it's not a problem with the base geometries as far as I can tell.

Comment: @rbanick I recall that multipolygons can't have adjoining  or overlapping parts.  I will check it out and change my answer when I get by a computer

Comment: I'm using this polygon layer: http://ebolageonode.org/layers/geonode%3Asle_admn_ad2_py_ocha_district